# Intuition Behind Step In Power Series Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion, intuition

When solving an ODE by the power series method, one ends up with an expression multiplied by $x^n$ inside a summation equaling $0$, and the next step is to set that expression equal to $0$.  For example, $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (na_{n + 1} + a_{n + 1} - 3a_n)x^n = 0$$ becomes $$na_{n + 1} + a_{n + 1} - 3a_n = 0.$$  Is there a geometric intuition behind what is going on with this step that makes it obvious why this is the right thing to do?

Comment: The series on the right side is $\sum  0x^n$.  Since the series are equal, the coefficients are equal.

Comment: A polynomial is equivalent to $0$ if and only if all the coefficients are equal to $0$. Would you like a proof of this?